# What is the name of this area on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, what is this bright blue highlighted area called?

[image: IMAGE HERE]

I would like to change the color of it, but I'm not sure what it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vertical Ruler. The one on the right is the Overview Ruler.

Answer (score 2):

The bright blue highlighted area in the vertical ruler is called **range indicator**.

[Its color can be configured since Eclipse Photon (4.8)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#range-indicator-color).